# How do I display the bitmap image in the picture box?

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

Store an image with the ".raw" extension in a two-dimensional byte array. Convert it to bitmap. I want to show this in the picture box, but if I run it with the code below, I get an error that the parameter is wrong.

Width and height are obtained from the information provided by the header file.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

```
string filename = @"test.raw";
byte[] rawBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
int bytePixel = 2;
int width = samples*bytePixel;
int height = lines;
byte[,] rawData = new byte[height, width];
int counter = new int();

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++, counter++)
    {
        rawData[i, j] = rawBytes[counter];
    }
}
Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
BitmapData bitmapImageData = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormap.Format16bppGrayScale);

unsafe
{
    byte* pointer = (byte*)bitmapImageData.Scan0.ToPointer();
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++, pointer++)
        {
            *pointer = rawData[y, x];
        }
    }
}
bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapImageData);
pictureBox1.Image = bitmapImage;
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Your image is not true color image and its rows require to be memory-aligned. You should take the stride value of image into account. You should also set the pixels short by short, not byte by byte.

Comment: a) why don't you tell us just which line throws the error?? b) Format16bppGrayScale is not really well supported and I doubt a pbox can handle it, even if it is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what's wrong but if you just want to see byte array result on screen, this func will make bmp file with IntPtr. Hope it helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var fs = new FileStream("test.bmp", FileMode.Open);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 600, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

        BitmapData bitmapdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)bitmapdata.Scan0.ToPointer();                
            for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 800; j++)
                {
                    *p = (byte)(i * j); p++;
                }
            }
        }
        FileSaveBMP($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.bmp", bitmapdata.Scan0, new CRect() { Width = 800, Height = 600 }, 800);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);
        //pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }

    private unsafe void FileSaveBMP(string sFile, IntPtr ptr, CRect rect, int w, int p_nByte = 1)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt16(0x4d42));
        if (p_nByte == 1)
        {
            if ((Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height > Int32.MaxValue) bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(54 + 1024 + p_nByte * 1000 * 1000));
            else bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(54 + 1024 + p_nByte * (Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height));
        }
        else if (p_nByte == 3)
        {
            if ((Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height > Int32.MaxValue) bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(54 + p_nByte * 1000 * 1000));//uint bfSize = br.ReadUInt32();
            else bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(54 + p_nByte * (Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height));//uint bfSize = br.ReadUInt32();
        }

        //image 크기 bw.Write();   bmfh.bfSize = sizeof(14byte) + nSizeHdr + rect.right * rect.bottom;
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt16(0));   //reserved // br.ReadUInt16();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt16(0));   //reserved //br.ReadUInt16();
        if (p_nByte == 1)
            bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(1078));
        else if (p_nByte == 3)
            bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(54));//uint bfOffBits = br.ReadUInt32();

        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(40));// uint biSize = br.ReadUInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(rect.Width));// nWidth = br.ReadInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(rect.Height));// nHeight = br.ReadInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt16(1));// a = br.ReadUInt16();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt16(8 * p_nByte));     //byte       // nByte = br.ReadUInt16() / 8;                
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(0));      //compress //b = br.ReadUInt32();
        if ((Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height > Int32.MaxValue) bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(1000 * 1000));// b = br.ReadUInt32();
        else bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32((Int64)rect.Width * (Int64)rect.Height));// b = br.ReadUInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(0));//a = br.ReadInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(0));// a = br.ReadInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(256));      //color //b = br.ReadUInt32();
        bw.Write(Convert.ToUInt32(256));      //import // b = br.ReadUInt32();
        if (p_nByte == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                bw.Write(Convert.ToByte(i));
                bw.Write(Convert.ToByte(i));
                bw.Write(Convert.ToByte(i));
                bw.Write(Convert.ToByte(255));
            }
        }
        if (rect.Width % 4 != 0)
        {
            rect.Right += 4 - rect.Width % 4;
        }
        byte[] aBuf = new byte[p_nByte * rect.Width];
        for (int i = rect.Height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)((long)ptr + rect.Left + ((long)i + (long)rect.Top) * w * p_nByte), aBuf, 0, rect.Width * p_nByte);
            bw.Write(aBuf);
        }
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}


public class CRect
{
    public int Left
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Right
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Top
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Bottom
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Above code creates image file like this.
[image]